# Why does the GDT have 3 entries for TLS?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am reading the "Understanding the Linux Kernel" book, and would like to understand the TLS entries in the GDT.

From the book, I take there are 3 entries in each processor's GDT table, that indicate the processor's current TLS segments.

What I am trying to understand is:

1. Why are there 3 TLS entries in the GDT table?
2. I have read that the segment selector %fs is commonly used to refer to a thread-local storage address, in the form (%fs:address). When does the fs register get populated with the TLS entry from the GDT?
3. Does the processor have a non-programmable register similar to the tr register but for the TLS entry?

I would expect a TLS entry to be modified in a processor's GDT at a process context switch, followed by storing the index of the TLS entry in the %fs register. But based on this description, a processor would only require 1 TLS entry in the GDT.